# IF cells begin with AND Create random number

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a sub, which determines if the cells in the 12th column starts with 262015. If it does start with this, it should create a new random 8-digit number starting with "18" and then 6 randomly created unique digits.

My code does not seem to figure out if the cell starts with 262015, and I have not been able to find help on creating the 8-digit number with these requirements.

Hope you can help me!

```
Sub Opgave8()

For i = 2 To 18288
    If Left(Worksheets("arab").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
        Worksheets("arab").Cells(i, 3) = "18" & studyid(6)
    End If
Next i

Function UniqueRandDigits(x As Long) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Integer
Dim s As String
Do
n = Int(Rnd() * 10)
If InStr(s, n) = 0 Then
s = s & n
i = i + 1
End If
Loop Until i = x + 1

UniqueRandDigits = s
End Function

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say *"unique digits"* do you mean each of the six should appear only once??

Comment: Exactly! Each of the six should only appear in the combination once :)

Answer (score 3):

```
For i = 2 To 18288
    If Left(Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
        Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 3) = "18" & Randdigits(6)
    End If
Next i

Function RandDigits(x As Long) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim s As String
For i = 1 To x
    s = s & Int(Rnd() * 10)
Next i
RandDigits = s
End Function
```

EDIT: here's one where all digits are different

```
Function UniqueRandDigits(x As Long) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Integer
Dim s As String
Do
n = Int(Rnd() * 10)
If InStr(s, n) = 0 Then
s = s & n
i = i + 1
End If
Loop Until i = x + 1

UniqueRandDigits = s
End Function
```

EDIT2: And here is one that forces all numbers to be different

```
dim n as  string
dim ok as boolean
For i = 2 To 18288
    If Left(Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
        ok = false
        do
        n = UniqueRandDigits(6)
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Base").Range("L2:L18288"), n) = 0 Then
                Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 3) = "18" & n
                ok = true
            end if
        loop until ok
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Does this code replace the cells found in the first part with a new random number? And is it possible to set it to "18XXXXXX" where the X's are random numbers?

Comment: But it does not satisfy the "Each of the six should only appear in the combination once" requirement

Comment: oh, missed that

Comment: Nice! How can i make it check that the combination only appear once, since its around 10.000 numbers its creating, which needs to be different? :)

Comment: It says that sub/function isnt defined - Where do you put the Sub / End sub tag? :)

Comment: I Changed the question to what i've written from your post now :)

Comment: Thats my bad - I wrote something wrong in the code... Thank you SO much for your help mate! My last question: Is there anything i can read to understand what you did? I have a good general understanding, but this code seems kind of complex tbh

Comment: Use F8 to step through the code. If you hover your cursor over the variables they should show the current values - (or use the Immediate window to find the values by typing ? and the variable name)  You should be able to work out what's happening at each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Left` function, you need to specify the `String`, then the number of characters from the left, and then you check if it's equal to "262015".

Try the code below:

```
For i = 2 To 18288
    If Left(Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
        Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 3) = "XXX"
    End If
Next i
```